# Array dimension reshape

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of dimension (300, 2, 17, 80) which is 300 samples of 2 images of dimension (17,80).
I'd like to reshape the array to feed my CNN such as (300, 17, 80, 2).
How can I do that ?
Thanks for the support.

Comment: [`numpy.swapaxes()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [np.moveaxis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html) for that purpose. For example,

```
import numpy as np
M = np.zeros((300,2,17,80))
print(M.shape)
M = np.moveaxis(M, 1, -1)
print(M.shape)
```

The `np.moveaxis(M, 1, -1)` call moves the second axis with axis index=1 to the last position by using the axis index=-1.